# Effectively logging sqlalchemy to a file?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql

I am using pandas & sqlalchemy to store data from an API connection in a PostreSQL database.

Now, I want to log what is happening; if the connection was successful, the SQL query, was the table created/replaced/appended, how many rows were added etc, useful info like that.

So, I set up a logger to log to a file;

```
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(name)s -%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
log = logging.getLogger("sqlalchemy")
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("sqlalchemy.engine")
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(file_handler)
```

This outputs to "sqlalchemy.engine" file, but there's hundreds & hundreds of lines and I'm not entirely sure what's relevant and what isn't?

Is there a way for me to just log details such as if the connection was successful, the SQL query, was the table created/replaced/appended, how many rows were added etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can rather do import logging and then set the log level and its file path.
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html